# How to update multiple behaviors in code to the same property on a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

WPF .NET4.5

*The Problem: When the ListSource dependency property on the ImageCanvas is set, only the last behavior, "MyList", actually gets updated.* It is as if the last behavior overwrites all the previous bindings.

*How can I have all the behaviors updated when the ListSource on the ImageCanvas is updated?*

I have a custom control with a ListSource dependency property:

```
public class ImageCanvas : ContentControl
    {
 public FrameElement ListSource
        {
            get { return (FrameElement)GetValue(ListSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ListSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ListSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ListSource", typeof(FrameElement), typeof(ImageCanvas),
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                    (s,e) =>
                    {
                        // The ListBehavior will be called before this dependency property of ImageCanvas.
                        ImageCanvas ic = s as ImageCanvas;
                        ic.Content = ((FrameElement)e.NewValue).DataContext;
                    }
                    ));

    }
}
```

The XAML is:

```
<ctrl:ImageCanvas x:Name="ImageCanvas"
                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Aquamarine" 
                        Panel.ZIndex="{Binding ImageLayer.ZIndex}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding ImageLayer.Visibility}" 
                         >
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <b:ImageCanvasBehavior  x:Name="MyZoom" />
                        <b:MovieBehavior x:Name="MyMovie"       />
                        <b:MusicBehavior x:Name="MyMusic"       />
                        <b:ListBehavior x:Name="MyList"         />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </ctrl:ImageCanvas>
```

Each behavior is bound to the ListSource custom property of the ImageCanvas when the ImageCanvas is loaded by the XAML.

In the behaviors:

```
private void IC_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ic = AssociatedObject as ImageCanvas;

            var bindingListSource = new Binding();
            bindingListSource.Source = this;
            bindingListSource.Path = new PropertyPath(ListSourceProperty);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(ic, ImageCanvas.ListSourceProperty, bindingListSource);
        }

 public FrameElement ListSource
        {
            get { return (FrameElement)GetValue(ListSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ListSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ListSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ListSource", typeof(FrameElement), typeof(ListBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null,
                (s,e) =>
                {
                    var behavior = s as ListBehavior;
                    var ic = behavior.AssociatedObject as ImageCanvas;

                    if ((FrameElement)e.NewValue == (FrameElement)e.OldValue)
                        return;

                    CurrentFrame = ((FrameElement)e.NewValue).Frame;
                }
                ));
```

*The Problem: When the ListSource dependency property on the ImageCanvas is set, only the last behavior, "MyList", actually gets updated.* It is as if the last behavior overwrites all the previous bindings.

*How can I have all the behaviors updated when the ListSource on the ImageCanvas is updated?*

Edit#1: To better explain, I have defined a "FrameElement" as:

```
public class FrameElement : UIElement
    {
        public object DataContext { get; set; }
        public int Frame { get; set; }
        public ListTypeEnum ListType { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

The ContentControl is being used to display only one item at a time, DataTemplates in Resources are being used to implicitly change the display based on the DataContext (this works well). The DataContext may or may not have a collection, depending on what the DataContext is for the current display (hence the "Frame" number). The problem is that each behavior will need to determine if the current datacontext applies to itself--so each behavior, as listed in the XAML, needs to receive the current FrameElement when it is set on the ContentControl, i.e., the "ImageCanvas".

I hope that better explains my scenario.

TIA.

Edit#2:
If the BindingOperations are removed from the behaviors, and the XAML changed to directly bind, (see below), then all the behaviors are updated correctly! **So the question now becomes, how can the XAML code be replicated correctly in the behavior to achieve the same result???**

Working XAML code:

```
  <ctrl:ImageCanvas x:Name="ImageCanvas"
                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Aquamarine" 
                            Panel.ZIndex="{Binding ImageLayer.ZIndex}" 
                            Visibility="{Binding ImageLayer.Visibility}" 
                             >
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <b:ImageCanvasBehavior  x:Name="MyZoom" 
             ListSource="{Binding ElementName=ImageCanvas, Path=ListSource}" />
                            <b:MovieBehavior x:Name="MyMovie"       
             ListSource="{Binding ElementName=ImageCanvas, Path=ListSource}" />
                            <b:MusicBehavior x:Name="MyMusic"       
             ListSource="{Binding ElementName=ImageCanvas, Path=ListSource}" />
                            <b:ListBehavior x:Name="MyList"         
             ListSource="{Binding ElementName=ImageCanvas, Path=ListSource}" />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </ctrl:ImageCanvas>
```

Comment: i am not sure to understood your code and what you want to do , but the ListSource is not a collection ? the behaviours are allready in an attached collection in the ImageCanvas ? please explain a bit more

Comment: @GCamel Thanks. Please see my above Edits.  My ListSource--poorly named--actually holds a "FrameElement" that has a datacontext property. Only the last behavior, "MyList", receives the update from the ContentControl, "ImageCanvas".  Is this a bug?  :)

Comment: @GCamel Changing the XAML to directly bind solved the problem, but begs the question of how to replicate these bindings from within each behavior to achieve the same result. Any ideas?